# Spring не может найти bean repository

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

Никак Spring не хочет находить bean:

```
@Repository
```

public interface CartRepository extends JpaRepository{

}
Вызываю так:

```
@Autowired
private CartRepository repository;
```

---

**UPD:** Добавил конструктор с параметром:

```
@Autowired
public CartService(CartRepository repository, ProductRepository pRepository){
    this.repository = repository; 
    this.pRepository = pRepository;
}
```

Теперь получаю такое:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
Error creating bean with name 'cartService' defined in file
[E:\test\test\target\test-1.0\WEB-INF\classes\com\test\service\CartService.class]:
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with
index 0 of type [com.test.repository.GenericRepository]: : No
qualifying bean of type [com.test.repository.GenericRepository]
found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as
autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {};
nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
qualifying bean of type [com.test.repository.GenericRepository]
found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as
autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}  at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:730)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:196)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1045)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:949)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628)
    at
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at
org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
    at
org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
    at
org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4736)
    at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5181)
    at
org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at
org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:586)
    at
org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:460)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1586)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at
com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at
com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at
org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1460)
    at
org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:906)
    at
org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:344)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)     at
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)    at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at
org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at
org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
    at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:614)
    at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at
org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
    at
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


Caused by:
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
qualifying bean of type [com.test.repository.GenericRepository]
found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as
autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}  at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:988)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:770)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:795)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:723)
    ... 63 more
```

В чем проблема может быть?

Comment: Пробовали ставить над интерфейсом GenericRepository аннотацию @Repository? Должен же как то spring определить, что из этого класса надо сделать бин.

Comment: @Bakhuss поставил, но результат тот же самый

Comment: Попробуйте добавить конструктор с параметром GenericRepository<Cart, Long> repository, и над ним поставить @Autowired

Comment: @Bakhuss обновил

Comment: Если вообще убрать поле private GenericRepository<Cart, Long> repository, второй, который pRepository, создаётся?

Comment: @Bakhuss нет. Добавил stack который получаю

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нельзя так писать **`MyRepository<EntityType, IdType> extends JpaRepository<EntityType, IdType>`**

**Подумайте над тем, что происходит:** при запуске приложения Spring "проходиться" по всем репозиториям и "на лету" создает классы, которые реализуют интерфейсы (в Вашем случае это `GenericRepository`). А теперь подумайте как Spring будет создавать класс, который реализует вот такой инферфейс `GenericRepository<EntityType, IdType>`, **откуда он возьмет тип для `EntityType` и `IdType`**?

Comment: Добавил репозитории для сущностей, результат тот же

Comment: @DmitriyKruglov аннотация `@EnableJpaRepositories` стоит?

Comment: @DmitriyKruglov еще уберите аннотацию `@Autowired` с поля (private CartRepository repository). Вы же используете инжекцию с помощью конструктора.

Comment: сначало вылетела `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Environment must not be null!`, перешел на другую версию спринга и все то же самое

Comment: @DmitriyKruglov откуда я могу знать почему у Вас `Enviroment = null`? Добавьте логи.

Comment: `Enviroment != null` переходом на другую версию. Но проблема вышеописанная все еще актуальна.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83678/discussion-between-not-a-programmer-and-dmitriy-kruglov).

Comment: Так что в итоге получилось? JpaRepository должен на этапе компиляции знать, с каким классом и типом ID он будет работать? То есть, ему нельзя указывать <T,ID>, а необходимы конкретные данные?